# How to do form validation in React similar to Angular?

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a project that uses both Angular and React for different parts of the application. I have a form in Angular that uses built-in validation features to check if the input fields are populated and valid. For example, I have a `name` field that is required and has a `has-error` class if it is empty or invalid.

Here is my Angular code:

```
<div
  class="form-group"
  ng-class="{ 'has-error' : validating && form.name.$invalid }"
>
  <label for="name" class="col-md-3 control-label">Name</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <input
      type="text"
      id="name"
      name="description"
      ng-model="name"
      class="form-control"
      required
    />
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to do something similar in React, but I don't know how to implement form validation.

Can anyone please help me with this problem? How can I do form validation in React similar to Angular? What are the best practices or libraries for this problem?

Comment: You can handle form validation manually, or using 3rd party to handle the form, for example `react-hook-form` or `formilk`

Comment: not sure what you mean , is there an example ? As i am trying to write existing Angular JS code in React

Comment: Oke, give me a minute. I will give you some demo. Edited: I see someone has already posts a code for you :D

Comment: I have updated my demo below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can do that. The easiest way is to use third party library such as `react-hook-form`.

For example:

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="name" className="col-md-3 control-label">
          Name
        </label>
        <div className="col-md-9">
          <input
            type="text"
            id="name"
            name="name"
            {...register("name", { required: true })}
            className="form-control"
          />
          {formState.isDirty && formState.errors.name && (
            <span className="has-error">Name is required</span>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

This way, you can implement validation in the form.

To learn more, please see [React Hook Form Documentation](https://www.react-hook-form.com/get-started/).

Answer (score 0):

For simple form, you can handle it manually using `useState`, [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-fpf7xk?file=/src/index.js)

But for complicated form you can use 3rd party like [react-hook-form](https://www.react-hook-form.com/get-started/#Applyvalidation) to handle form. It has some features like watch the field change, schema validate...:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <div className={`form-group ${errors.name ? "has-error" : ""}`}>
    <label htmlFor="name" className="col-md-3 control-label">
      Name
    </label>
    <div className="col-md-9">
      <input
        type="text"
        id="name"
        name="name"
        className="form-control"
        {...register("name", { required: true })}
      />
    </div>
    {errors.name && <p className="error">Name is required</p>}
  </div>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-get-started-forked-46pjty?file=/src/index.js)